# Sort ArrayList inside ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

How I can sort skills which is inside another ArrayList as descending order? We have an
Employee class with id, name and
skills. Skills is a separate list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Employee> employees = Arrays.asList(
            new Employee(101, "Ehsan", Arrays.asList("Java", "Spring Boot", "Hibernate", "Spring", "Java", "Net")),
            new Employee(102, "Jamshid", Arrays.asList("Java", "Marketing")),
            new Employee(103, "KK",
                    Arrays.asList("Payroll Management", "Human Resource", "Leaves", "Time Sheet")),
            new Employee(104, "Priya", Arrays.asList("Medicine", "Surgery")));


    
  
    
   for(Employee l: employees) {
       System.out.println(l);
   }

    
}

Expected o/p:
Ehsan : {[Java, Spring Boot, Hibernate, Spring, Java, Net]} 
KK : {[Payroll Management, Human Resource, Leaves, Time Sheet]} 
Jamshid : {[Java, Marketing]} 
Priya : {[Medicine, Surgery]}
```

Comment: If you need it all the time, the constructor of `Employee` could sort the list it gets.

Comment: Note that `Arrays.asList` does *not* return a `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: `List` itself has `sort()` in any contemporary Java version: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator- - oh, maybe that remark was about the tag.

Comment: The expected output does'nt match your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Comparator.comparingInt` to sort based on the sizes of the skills `List`.

```
employees.sort(Comparator.<Employee>comparingInt(e -> e.getSkills().size()).reversed());
```

Before Java 8, you can use the following:

```
employees.sort(new Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final Employee o1, final Employee o2) {
       return Integer.compare(o2.getSkills().size(), o1.getSkills().size());
    }
});
```

Comment: For added fun, OP wanted descending order :-)

Comment: I mean with descending order this way: Ehsan has 6 skills so it comes first and KK has 4 skills and comes in second and so on.

Comment: Can you use Java 7 for your answer?

Comment: @ehsanhosseini Updated.

Comment: @ehsanhosseini Glad to help.

Comment: To compare the sizes.

Comment: How I can make skills in ascending order? For example skills for kk in ascending order like KK : {[Human Resource, Leaves, Payroll Management,  Time Sheet]}

Comment: @ehsanhosseini Use `Integer.compare(o1.getSkills().size(), o2.getSkills().size());`